# Click event not working on same class buttons except first button

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating store app, and after every product have add to cart btn. When i try to fire click event with that btn it works with first product, But it doesn't work with other product buttons. Data is coming from mangoose and i used pug on it. Everything aligned i checked many times all products buttons have same class.

Here is html and pug code

```html
<ul class="posts">
    <li class="posts_list">
        <div class="posts_list-box1">
            <a class="posts_list-box1-link" href="/theme/space-journey-theme"><img class="posts_list-box1-img" src="./img/4.png" alt="Space Journey Theme"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="posts_list-box2">
            <h1 class="posts_list-box2-name">Space Journey Theme</h1>
            <h3 class="posts_list-box2-author">by Crippy Themes </h3></div>
        <div class="posts_list-box3">
            <button class="btn-small btn-small_full" href="/theme/space-journey-theme">More Details</button>
            <button class="btn-small btn-small_outline cartBtn" data-id="5e3691dcbd2e3745386aa470">Add to Cart</button>
            <h4 class="posts_list-box3-price">$59</h4></div>
    </li>
    <li class="posts_list">
        <div class="posts_list-box1">
            <a class="posts_list-box1-link" href="/theme/business-enterpreneur-protfolio"><img class="posts_list-box1-img" src="./img/1.png" alt="Business | Enterpreneur Protfolio"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="posts_list-box2">
            <h1 class="posts_list-box2-name">Business | Enterpreneur Protfolio</h1>
            <h3 class="posts_list-box2-author">by Crippy Themes </h3></div>
        <div class="posts_list-box3">
            <button class="btn-small btn-small_full" href="/theme/business-enterpreneur-protfolio">More Details</button>
            <button class="btn-small btn-small_outline cartBtn" data-id="5e3695546dc5fd456c7c7726">Add to Cart</button>
            <h4 class="posts_list-box3-price">$29</h4></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Pug code

```
ul.posts
    each data in theme
      li.posts_list
        .posts_list-box1
          a.posts_list-box1-link(href=`/theme/${data.slug}`)
            img.posts_list-box1-img(src=`./img/${data.mainImg}` alt=`${data.name}`)
        .posts_list-box2
          h1.posts_list-box2-name=data.name
          h3.posts_list-box2-author by Crippy Themes 
        .posts_list-box3
          button.btn-small.btn-small_full(href=`/theme/${data.slug}`) More Details
          button.btn-small.btn-small_outline.cartBtn( data-id=`${data._id}`) Add to Cart
          h4.posts_list-box3-price= `$${data.price}
```

Javascript code

```js
document.querySelector('.cartBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('clicked');
        document.querySelector('.bucket').setAttribute('style', ' opacity: 1; visibility: visible; transform: translateY(0)');
    })
```

Comment: By "not working", are you saying when you click the other buttons, "clicked" is not logged?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.cartBtn')` selects the first element with that className. Use `document.querySelectorAll('.cartBtn')` and a `for-loop`. Right now, you only assign the click event to the first element having that className.

Comment: @technophyle nothing works it's cart button this button work is to show bucket but only first button is showing not others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the click event to all `button.cartBtn` elements and not just the first one.
[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first matching element whereas [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall) returns a `NodeList`.

```js
for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('.cartBtn'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
    tL[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('clicked');
        document.querySelector('.bucket').setAttribute('style', ' opacity: 1; visibility: visible; transform: translateY(0)');
    })
};
```